# Start gfxui.exe in the System32 folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I am writing a program using visual studio 2013 in C# and I need to start the Intel Graphics program. I have found the program in `C:\Windows\System32` and it is called `gfxui.exe`. I have tried all sorts of things, but it keeps saying that it cannot find the file. This is my current code to call the program:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
Process v;
v = Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\System32\gfxui.exe");
```

An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: The system cannot find the file specified

Above is the error that i get when running the code. This was tested running Visual Studio as administrator.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
C:\Users\Craig>dir C:\Windows\System32\gfxui.exe
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 1084-E8E0

 Directory of C:\Windows\System32

01/30/2014  12:02 AM         5,904,856 GfxUI.exe
               1 File(s)      5,904,856 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  28,730,310,656 bytes free

C:\Users\Craig>start gfxui.exe
```

I ran these 2 commands in cmd. the second opened up my program.

Comment: You probably need to run your application as Administrator.

Comment: When you open a command shell and run "dir C:\Windows\System32\gfxui.exe" - what is the result?  I ask because on my machine the app is named "gfxuiex.exe" so I would expect the error you are seeing in my environment.

Comment: Does visual studio have a run as administrator option for testing? I am new to visual studio.

Comment: Right click Visual Studio icon, `Run as administrator`.

Comment: I tried that and it still did not work.

Comment: I installed the software and then ran the program, but it still did not find it. is there a way to have it start a shortcut and then i can just place a shortcut in the folder.

Comment: I'm experiencing a related problem. GfxUI.exe is an extremely weird beast. If I run it manually at a command line, it runs. If I put it in a .bat file and double-click the .bat file, it runs. But if I set up a hotkey (using AutoHotkey), to call GfxUI, it doesn't run. If I make a hotkey to run that .bat file I set up earlier, all the *other* lines in the .bat file run fine, but I get `'C:\Windows\system32\GfxUI.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`. Why can I run it directly but not through a hotkey?

Comment: What's especially weird is that **GfxUI's own hotkey** (which by default is `<Ctrl><Alt>F12` doesn't work.  Well, I should say that all of this stuff (including AutoHotkey and GfxUI's own hotkey) was working fine yesterday.  Last night the computer was restarted to install some Windows 7 updates.  It would seem one of the updates broke this functionality.  (Maybe a security fix closed a "loophole" for hotkeys that had already been closed for C#?)